# Ethereum geth cli is broken after running geth personal.newAccount() password

Tags: json, blockchain, ethereum, geth

I'm on OS X.

Following this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.org/from-what-is-blockchain-to-building-a-blockchain-within-an-hour-4e738efc819d

I ran into some trouble where the author says to run `geth personal.newAccount()` in the geth console:

> Creating a Blockchain
>   The following creates the Blockchain, with the maxpeers command is set to 0 to disable the network.
>   mkdir eth-data
>   geth --datadir eth-new genesis.json init eth-new/genesis.json --networkid 123 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 console
>   In the geth console, type the following to make a new account and create a new password by typing in whatever you want. You will have to type your new password twice.
>   personal.newAccount()

I didn't see a console cursor so plugged that in the command line, followed by a password.

```
geth personal.newAccount()\npassword
```

Now when I try to run any geth command I get this:

> geth:129: command not found:password.

I deleted with `brew uninstall`, reinstalled, same problem. I killed all processes and looked for a config file in a variety of places.

Any thoughts on how to start over or fix this problem?

Comment: Long shot, but I'd check your OS aliases, my guess is that `geth` alias got messes up. Aliases are usually loaded at initialization of your shell so look in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command:

```
geth personal.newAccount('your_password')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was low memory. I tried running on a node with 0.5 GB and later one with 1 GB. It consistently failed with the following message on 0.5 GB node.

```
> personal.newAccount()
Password: 
Repeat password: 
Error: Post http://myhostname:8545: EOF
```

At the same time of above error, geth running on that node crashed with just a single work on stdout: `Killed`.

Increasing memory to 1 GB fixed the issue.

This link gave the clues: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2607